# fs.readFileSync doesn't do anything in case the file doesn't exist

Tags: node.js, fs

I am trying to read content of the file with this code:

```
 var content = fs.readFileSync(filename);
```

It works fine when file with such filename exists. However, it doesn't do anything if the file doesn't exist. It just hangs there forever.

One solution could be to check if the file exists before I try to read it, but I was hoping that would be part of the `fs` module so it would return undefined or any error that I could conveniently handle.

This is almost my entire code, can you see any issues? I can't.

```
for (var i=0; i<configFiles.length;i++){
    waterfallMain(configFiles[i]);
   }

//var importDefinition = config.importDefinition;
function waterfallMain(configFile){
    async.waterfall([
            function(callback){
                sftpHandler.downloadFile(credentials.host, credentials.username, credentials.password, credentials.path+configFile.importFileName, callback);
                console.log("Downloading done. Changing file encoding and reading data.");
                readFileSync_encoding(configFile.importFileName, "ISO-8859-1", callback);
            },
            function(fileData, callback) {
                mainProcess(fileData, callback);
            },
            function(data, callback) {
                postImportDefinition(data,  callback);
            },

            function(data, uri, callback) {
                postData(data, uri, callback);
            },

            function(syncUri, callback) {
                getSyncResponseInIntervals(syncUri, callback);
            }],

        // the bonus final callback function
        function(err, status) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            console.log(status);
            return;
        });
}



function readFileSync_encoding(filename, encoding, callback) {
      var content = fs.readFileSync(filename);
      callback(null, iconvlite.decode(content, encoding));
      return;
}
```

**EDIT:**

The problem was actually in the IDE I've been using c9.io

When I ran it locally I've received the error.
Interesting discovery.

Comment: When I run that command on a non-existent file it throws an exception: `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'not-here.txt'`. Are you sure you're not catching and silently ignoring the exception?

Comment: It's true that would explain it. I am having that method called in waterfall and even if I put console log at the point where I should catch errors, or I put a breakpoint, it doesn't get executed. I have no other handling. Will do a better check though.

Answer (score 1):

You could try checking for its existance first:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var content = '';

if(fs.accessSync(filename, fs.R_OK)) {
 content = fs.readFileSync(filename);
}

console.log(content);
```

**UPDATE**: Providing help around async methods:

```
function waterfallMain(configFile){
    async.waterfall([
            function(callback){
              fs.readFile(configFile, callback);
            },
            function(fileData, callback) {
               //fileData will now contain the contents of the "configFile", if it exists.
               mainProcess(fileData, callback);
            }
    ], function(err, status) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(status);
    });
```

See [fs.accessSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_accesssync_path_mode) documentation for more details.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Now it's hanging on this part: `fs.accessAsync(filename, fs.R_OK)`

Comment: Why are you using the `*sync` methods anyway? Your code will block until the values are returned.. As you're using `async` already you could just return the value of `fs.readFile`, for example `fs.readFile(callback)`

Comment: Not sure I understand. I am new to node so I might be doing something wrong. But I assumed I had to do it as a `sync` method because I need to wait until I get all the values before I go further.

Comment: See updated answer for how this could fit into your project.

Comment: Thank you, I see now. In any case how is this supposed to help with the issue I've got? Even though it's async, it's still sync due to waterfall, right? Does it have any advantages? Since I am trying to force it to be sync anyway.

Comment: `async` is not sync, as its name suggests. It's more about structuring your code in a way that's easier to understand. You should avoid using `*sync` methods as they will not perform under load, as the entire process halts. Perhaps [this link](http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/) will answer some of your questions.

Answer (score -1):

Write a function that returns either a string or null

```
 const Fs = require('fs');

 const readFile = (filename, encoding) => {

     try {
         return Fs.readFileSync(filename).toString(encoding);
     }
     catch (e) {
         return null;
     }
 };

 const contents = readFile(./somefile', 'utf8');
 // contents will be null if it doesn't exist or a string of utf8 if it does
```